# ModuleNotFoundError when running functional python tests despite that textX command works

Tags: textx

I followed the set of [instructions](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#get-started) for this open source.

At step 3, I am supposed to run

```
py.test tests/functional/
```

When I do so, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textx'
```

However, when I type `textx`, it's definitely working as a command.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The PYTHONPATH is not set by py.test, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html#pythonpath

As described in https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md you install textX in your virtual environment. If you omit 'pip install -e .' you get the described behavior.

As mentioned above, you can set the PYTHONPATH manually. Alternatively you can also run 'python -m pytest tests/functional' as proposed on the py.test website.

It is unclear to me why the textx command works in your example. Maybe you installed textX outside your virtual environment after creating the virtual environment?

Comment: >you installed textX outside your virtual environment after creating the virtual environment?

Yes. It's a distinct possibility. I did run `pip install -e`. I guess I will leave it as that.

Answer (score 1):

Run `export PYTHONPATH=.` before running the `py.test tests/functional/` and it should work.

This error may have occurred because I installed textX outside my virtual environment after creating the virtual environment.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. If you run `pip list` do you see `textX` with a location of your local git clone?

Comment: Now that I see it, but then it's after I run `export PYTHONPATH=.` so I am not sure if that has any effect